# Как сделать красивое затухание объекта?

Tags: python, анимация, pyqt, qlineedit, qpropertyanimation

Допустим, при вводе неправильного пароля ободок `QLineEdit`, 
в которого вводили пароль, становиться зелёным, если пароль правильный, 
и красный если неправильный.

А как сделать так, чтобы этот ободок появлялся и постепенно исчезал?

Comment: Думаю, можно попробовать через QTimer + qt style sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ **@S.Nick** дал интересную идею по поводу создания своего qt-свойства и использования `QPropertyAnimation` вместо `QTimer`.

Немного топорно получилось, да и свойство вместе с **QLineEdit**-ом я бы перенес в класс-наследник `PasswordLineEdit`, в котором и проверка была бы и анимация, но я хотел показать вам принцип.

Код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Animation check password')

        self.le_target_password = QLineEdit('123')

        self.le_current_password = QLineEdit()
        self.le_current_password.textEdited.connect(self._on_check_password)

        self.label_result = QLabel()

        main_layout = QFormLayout()
        main_layout.addRow('Current password', self.le_target_password)
        main_layout.addRow('Password', self.le_current_password)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label_result)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'password_border_color')
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)  # Продолжительность 1 секунда
        self.animation.setStartValue(0.0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(1.0)

    def set_border_color_password(self, value):
        color = '0, 100, 0' if self.is_correct_password() else '255, 0, 0'
        self.le_current_password.setStyleSheet(f'border: 3px solid rgba({color}, {value});')

    password_border_color = pyqtProperty(float, None, set_border_color_password)

    def is_correct_password(self):
        return self.le_target_password.text() == self.le_current_password.text()

    def _on_check_password(self):
        text = '<font color="{}">{}</font>'

        if self.is_correct_password():
            text = text.format('darkgreen', 'Пароль правильный!')
        else:
            text = text.format('red', 'Пароль неправильный!')

        self.animation.start()

        self.label_result.setText(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

Скриншоты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте некоторые анимационные эффекты:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore    import (QRectF, Qt, QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty,
                             QPoint, QParallelAnimationGroup, QEasingCurve)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter, QPainterPath, QColor, QPen


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Aнимационные эффекты")
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Введите Password и нажмите Return или Enter')
        self.lineEdit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.on_text_lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Выход', self, clicked=self.doClose))

        # Класс анимации прозрачности окна
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'windowOpacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)      # Продолжительность 1 секунда

        # Выполните затухание 
        self.doShow()

    def doShow(self):
        try:
            self.animation.finished.disconnect(self.close)
        except:
            pass
        self.animation.stop()
        # Диапазон прозрачности постепенно увеличивается от 0 до 1
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(1)
        self.animation.start()

    def doClose(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.close)  # Закройте окно, когда анимация завершена
        # Диапазон прозрачности постепенно уменьшается от 1 до 0
        self.animation.setStartValue(1)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        self.animation.start()


    def on_text_lineEdit(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text() == "12345":
            msg = 'Мы приветствуем Вас любимый пользователь!'
        else:
            self.lineEdit.setText("")
            msg = 'Что-то пошло не так, повторите попытку!' #self.msgEdit.text().strip()

        if not msg:
            return
        if hasattr(self, "_blabel"):
            self._blabel.stop()
            self._blabel.deleteLater()
            del self._blabel
        self._blabel = BubbleLabel()
        self._blabel.setText(msg)
        self._blabel.show()            



class BubbleLabel(QWidget):

    BackgroundColor = QColor(195, 195, 195)
    BorderColor     = QColor(150, 150, 150)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        text = kwargs.pop("text", "")
        super(BubbleLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Установить топлесс
        self.setWindowFlags(
            Qt.Window | Qt.Tool | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)

        # Установите минимальную ширину и высоту
        self.setMinimumWidth(200)
        self.setMinimumHeight(48)

        # Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground Указывает, что виджет должен иметь полупрозрачный фон, ...
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(8, 8, 8, 16)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setText(text)

        # Получить высоту и ширину экрана
        self._desktop = QApplication.instance().desktop()
        print("\nQApplication.instance().desktop() ", self._desktop)

    def setText(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

    def text(self):
        return self.label.text()

    def stop(self):
        self.hide()
        self.animationGroup.stop()
        self.close()

    def show(self):
        super(BubbleLabel, self).show()
        # начальная позиция окна
        startPos = QPoint(500, 250)
        endPos   = QPoint(600, 50)
        self.move(startPos)
        # инициализировать анимацию
        self.initAnimation(startPos, endPos)

    def initAnimation(self, startPos, endPos):
        # Прозрачная анимация
        opacityAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"opacity")
        opacityAnimation.setStartValue(1.0)
        opacityAnimation.setEndValue(0.0)
        # Установите кривую анимации
        opacityAnimation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InQuad)
        opacityAnimation.setDuration(4000)                 # Завершено через 4 секунды
        # Перемещение анимации вверх
        moveAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"pos")
        moveAnimation.setStartValue(startPos)
        moveAnimation.setEndValue(endPos)
        moveAnimation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InQuad)
        moveAnimation.setDuration(5000)                    #  Завершено через 5 секунд
        # Параллельная группа анимации (цель состоит в том, чтобы сделать эти две анимации одновременно)
        self.animationGroup = QParallelAnimationGroup(self)
        self.animationGroup.addAnimation(opacityAnimation)
        self.animationGroup.addAnimation(moveAnimation)
        self.animationGroup.finished.connect(self.close)  # Закройте окно, когда анимация заканчивается
        self.animationGroup.start()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(BubbleLabel, self).paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)   # Сглаживание

        rectPath = QPainterPath()                      # Округленный прямоугольник
        triPath  = QPainterPath()                      # нижний треугольник

        height = self.height() - 8                     # смещение вверх 8
        rectPath.addRoundedRect(QRectF(0, 0, self.width(), height), 5, 5)
        x = self.width() / 5 * 4
        triPath.moveTo(x, height)             # Переход к нижней горизонтальной линии 4/5
        # Нарисуйте треугольник
        triPath.lineTo(x + 6, height + 8)
        triPath.lineTo(x + 12, height)

        rectPath.addPath(triPath)             # Добавить треугольник к предыдущему прямоугольнику

        # Пограничная щетка
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.BorderColor, 1, Qt.SolidLine,
                            Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        # фоновая кисть
        painter.setBrush(self.BackgroundColor)
        # рисовать форму
        painter.drawPath(rectPath)
        # Нарисуйте линию внизу треугольника, чтобы обеспечить тот же цвет, что и фон
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.BackgroundColor, 1,
                            Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        painter.drawLine(x, height, x + 12, height)

    def windowOpacity(self):
        return super(BubbleLabel, self).windowOpacity()

    def setWindowOpacity(self, opacity):
        super(BubbleLabel, self).setWindowOpacity(opacity)

    # Поскольку свойство непрозрачности не нужно переопределять в QWidget
    opacity = pyqtProperty(float, windowOpacity, setWindowOpacity)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]